# Video recording - unable to start camera preview

Tags: android, video, camera, mediarecorder

I'm working on a custom video recording class, and I'm having some issues getting the camera preview to display when the Activity first appears. I'm calling this function inside the `surfaceCreated` callback:

```
private void initRecorder(Surface surface) throws IOException {
// It is very important to unlock the camera before doing setCamera
// or it will results in a black preview
if(camera == null) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    camera.unlock();
}

if(recorder == null)
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
recorder.setCamera(camera);

camera.startPreview();

recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/test.mp4");
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(15000000);
recorder.setMaxDuration(10000); // length of video in MS
recorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);
recorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);


try {
    recorder.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // This is thrown if the previous calls are not called with the 
    // proper order
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

When the Activity starts, my app crashes saying:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed`

Above that error, I noticed a line saying:

`attempt to use a locked camera from a different process (old pid 4894, new pid 6405)`

When I step through the code, that error is occurring on the `camera.startPreview()` line. If I remove that line from my code, the preview shows up fine after I call `recorder.start()`, and prior to that I just have a black screen with my record button. Once I stop recording, the preview continues to show fine (I am calling `camera.startPreview()` after I stop recording).

Since I'm calling `camera.unlock()` only a few lines prior to starting the preview, and the two calls occur in the same function, how can I be having this error?

**Edit**: I tested the same code minus the call to `startPreview()` on a Droid X2 and a Droid 1, and it works fine. It looks like the EVO 4G is the problem. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: I have the same issue since a test-app crashed while having the cam locked :( Did you find out how to unlock since the question was last active?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I ended up not building a custom recorder after all was said and done.

Answer (score 0):

Arrange code like this and decrease video encoding rate.  It is very high for your video size.  This may not be creating a problem on your device because on some devices it is clipped internally.

```
private void initRecorder(Surface surface) throws IOException {
    // It is very important to unlock the camera before doing setCamera
    // or it will results in a black preview
    if (camera == null) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.unlock();
    }

    if (recorder == null)
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setCamera(camera);

    camera.startPreview();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(2048000);
    recorder.setMaxDuration(10000); // length of video in MS
    recorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);
    recorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/test.mp4");
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // This is thrown if the previous calls are not called with the
        // proper order
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered a very similar question here: [preview display in android media recorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176663/preview-display-in-android-media-recorder/31807171#31807171)

See if it helps you, it has a whole Activity that works with a preview and records a video.

Answer (score 0):

`camera.unlock()` must be called from the same thread where camera was locked before. Check your logs for messages like `Unlock call from pid 19322; currently locked to pid 17652`.

Note that lock can be set by calling `Camera.lock()` or `MediaRecorder.start()`

> Since API level 14, camera is automatically locked for applications in
>   MediaRecorder.start(). Applications can use the camera (ex: zoom)
>   after recording starts. There is no need to call this after recording
>   starts or stops.